# Office 365 only works on one single local account

Tags: macos, ms-office, user-account, office-365

I have a MS Office 365 University subscription. For separation of concerns between my private files I have two local accounts on my mac (latest el capitan). However, when I try to launch an office application on my second user account, it tells me to activate my office subscription.

How can I activate office 365 system wide across all my user accounts?

EDIT: Word Build: 15.22.1

Comment: What happens when you activate the subscription on the second user account? According to MS, you can use the subscription on [two devices](https://products.office.com/en-us/university) **"Get the fully installed Office experience on up to 2 PCs, Macs, or tablets and 2 phones (including Windows, Apple®, and Android™ devices)"**

Comment: I already activated it on my laptop (win) that I use at the university

Comment: Could you edit the post to list the build/version of the app you run to activate Office? Word 15.24 for example from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=525133

Comment: @bmike edited the question